# How does proto3 set the value of the map type

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-node

How to set the value of map type in static code?
I have a map structure like this.

```
message HelloRequest {
  Maps   maps = 1;
}
message Maps {
  map<string, AudioChannelCountMapBitrateOptions> formatMapChannelCount = 1;
}

message AudioChannelCountMapBitrateOptions{
  map<string, StringVec> bitrateMap = 1;
}

message StringVec{
  repeated string strings = 1;
}
```

After I generate the pb file, how do I use it?
StringVec provides a set method and a get method,so the strings field can be get and set like this.

```
const strVec = new messages.StringVec();
strVec.setStringsList(['1', '2']);
console.log(strVec.getStringsList());
```

But Maps and AudioChannelCountMapBitrateOptions only provide the get method, like getFormatmapchannelcountMap,getBitratemapMap.
How do I set the value of this map structure so that I can get a complete map data structure.
the map data structure like this? right?

```
formatMapChannelCount : {
  bitrateMap : ['1','2','3']
}
```

If you feel my description is not clear, please ask me questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated#map

The official document has instructions, but I actually only found it now.

Comment: This link is broken! Here is an archived link https://web.archive.org/web/20220422085026/https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated